# Configuring Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

So I'm new to dropzone.js and I have a simple html page. When I drag and drop files it looks like I'm able to do it. However, now I want to further configure this with some options like "clickable" , "addRemoveLinks", and "dictDefaultMessage".

I've looked for samples, can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here ? It doesn't appear to care about the configurations I've put in my javascript.  Any direction or suggestions would be most appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="Dropzone.js"></script>
<script>
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
  maxFilesize: 8, // MB
  clickable : true,
  uploadMultiple :true,
  addRemoveLinks:true,
  dictRemoveFile="Remove File",
  dictDefaultMessage="Hey Yo"
 
};

</script>


<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Jason

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. Have you got it working? What about putting the script where you want to apply the options after the html for the drop zone area. It may fail because the part of the page hasn't loaded yet so doesn't apply to anything. Also, in the example I think he uses a dash to separate the word in the html then camelCase when setting the options.

Answer (score 1):

For Dropzone script and your custom script to work. Dropzone must be included in the head section, so that they would load before every element. Else you can't combine configuration and auto capture together.

This helped me to unstuck myself when i got stucked.